# ProgressBar Not Showing in Android MarshMallow

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am getting problem with Progress bar in Android Marsh mallow.Its Working fine in other version.Progress not showing in Marsh mallow.Once check my xml code.

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/custom_progress" />
```

The below code is my custom_progress.xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false" >

    <item android:duration="10">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/load_00" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="10">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/load_01" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="10">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/load_02" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="10">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/load_03" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="10">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/load_04" />
    </item>
    <item android:duration="10">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/load_05" />
<animation-list/>
```

Please suggest me about this issue

Comment: Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: I did not getting any exception but the animation progress not showing.May be any problem with animation-list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally i got the solution may be it will helps to some one.I removed clip from animation list for android marshmallow like

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false"
    android:visible="true">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/load_00"
        android:duration="10" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/load_01"
        android:duration="10" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/load_02"
        android:duration="10" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/load_03"
        android:duration="10" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/load_04"
        android:duration="10" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/load_05"
        android:duration="10" />
<animation-list/>
```